# Short pedagogical introduction to Young-tableaux and weight diagrams?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics, young-tableaux

I am looking for a short pedagogical introduction to Young-tableaux and weight diagrams and the relationship between them. Hopefully one which would contain many detailed and worked out examples of applications of these methods in physics.

I am looking for a resource that is dedicated specifically to this topic, which I can easily print out, as opposed to a heavy general group-theory textbook.

Comment: Some starting points: the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) and a [short survey](http://yufeizhao.com/papers/youngtab-hcmr.pdf)

Comment: I don't know what "pedagogical" means in this context. What is a non-pedagogical introduction?

Comment: @angryavian the short survey link is broken. Please fix.

Comment: @ArB [Updated link](https://yufeizhao.com/research/youngtab-hcmr.pdf)